# Move weight attribute to the bottom on WooCommerce product page?

Tags: woocommerce

Is it possible to rearrange the attributes in WooCommerce? I have a 'Brand' attribute and like to display that before the 'Weight' attribute on the product page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_display_product_attributes` filter, and for instance sort the keys of the `$product_attributes` array in ascending order. That should but brand above weight.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_product_attributes', 'woocommerce_sort_product_attributes', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_sort_product_attributes ( $product_attributes, $product ) {
    ksort( $product_attributes );
    return $product_attributes;
}
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted.